# Share database/backend changes with team

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

We are normaly sharing source code with others using version controlling system. Is there any way to sharing database changes/admin changes with others using version controlling system or any other system? I'm using magento 2.1 and svn

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for database versioning you can use any of these tools:

- [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/index.html)

> Supports code branching and merging
>   Supports multiple developers
>   Supports multiple database types
>   Supports XML, YAML, JSON and SQL formats
>   Supports context-dependent logic
>   Cluster-safe database upgrades
>   Generate Database change documentation
>   Generate Database "diffs"
>   Run through your build process, embedded in your application or on demand
>   Automatically generate SQL scripts for DBA code review
>   Does not require a live database connection

- [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/)
- [c5-db-migration](https://code.google.com/archive/p/c5-db-migration/)
- [dbdeploy](http://dbdeploy.com/)
- [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/)
- [Sqitch](http://sqitch.org/)

admin loggers example:

https://amasty.com/admin-actions-log-for-magento-2.html

> Track all backend actions performed by store administrators. View detailed log history and monitor login attempts on a handy grid. Track admin actions in a real-time mode to easily improve admin users' performance.